# Does this make grammatical sense?

Tags: grammar

Does the following sentence make grammatical sense?

> Our relationship is an epitome of friendship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it.

Examples,

- Unfortunately, my daughter has yet to be married.
- Unfortunately, my true love has yet to appear.
- Fortunately, the party has yet to disperse (therefore, the party is still on).
- Unfortunately, the snow storm has yet to cease.

> [yet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yet)  (yt)
>   adv.
>   1. At this time; for the present: isn't ready yet.
>   2. Up to a specified time; thus far: The end had not yet come.
>   3. At a future time; eventually: may yet change his mind.
>   4. Besides; in addition: returned for yet another helping.
>   5. Still more; even: a yet sadder tale.
>   6. Nevertheless: young yet wise.
>   conj.
>   And despite this; nevertheless: She said she would be late, yet she arrived on time.

Explanation:
Yet used in this mode = "up until now still"

> My daughter has to get married, but up until now she still isn't.
>   My daughter has to get married. Unfortunately, up until now she still isn't.
>   My daughter has **up until now still** to get married.
>   My daughter has still to get married.
>   My daughter has yet to get married.